# Create Cognitive search index for databricks data

Tags: database, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying create azure cognitive search index for databricks using azure databricks.

The problem I am facing is while creating azure search from portal I see options like Azure cosmos DB, and azure Table etc, but no direct option for Databricks.

as having no option for feeding databricks data to it directly,  so what is the thing that i am missing or unaware about that helps create index for databricks?

The data is in tabular form, which is migrated from SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly add databricks data  as source while creating index.

You data should be in any one of this storage.

[image]

So, send you databricks data to any one this intermediate storage.

I am using `Blob Storage` here, you can use below code to to write your data to storage.

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/data",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Account_key>"})
```

After mounting write the data to single file.

Below is my data.

[image]

```
import os

directory_path = "/dbfs/mnt/data/cog"

if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
    os.makedirs(directory_path)

df.toPandas().to_json("/dbfs/mnt/data/cog/data.json",orient="records")
```

Here, you must prefix`dbfs` to your path.

This will create a single json file.

[image]

Now you can create index by selecting source as blob storage.

Goto **Import data** > select blob storage.

[image]

Add required details as shown below.

[image]

Then move to next step, at **Customize target index** you will find content and metadata.
There check mark your filters,sortables and retrievables.

[image]

Next click on create an indexer to create.

Query output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. it is really helpful.

I am using c# here and i read it can be done using REST APIs, do you have experience on that?

Comment: you are using databricks right ?it should be either scala or python.

Comment: i am supposed to use c# for development, so i have question, if databricks data can be moved to index using c#, but then in what format it could be, because i am seeing json input for REST APIs, which in my case not possible because i have so much data.

Comment: What do you mean by databricks data? is it dataframe ? If yes you need to write it down
to intermediate storage as shown above. You can not use c# inside databricks.
Yes, most of the time it is json format except for sql. Try sql if you have large data.

Comment: No data is moved from SQL to databricks bronze layer for security purpose. but i am have to create cognitive search index for that data to be used by an API, i need to give that data to Index

Comment: ok then directly give sql as the source while creating search index.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @JayashankarGS, Your answer was helpful. but Do you know about ways of transferring the data which is at at databricks to the Index, in some other way? as i am still finding solution for my scenario and i am not allowed to have the data at azure SQL.